# How to call libjpeg API in an erroneous way?

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I want to test my error handling code when using the `libjpeg` but I cannot find a suitable call which to produce an error. If I simply pass a `nullptr` to some of the calls expecting a pointer to a structure then the library just crashes. I want to find a statement that calls the set in the `jpeg_error_mgr`'s `error_exit` function.

Comment: Doesn't `libjpeg` library sources have tests?

Comment: Pass the functions handling the structured data some invalid data.

Comment: How about writing a wrapper to call the native libjpeg, and doing a mock in your testing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to produce an error when calling `libjpeg`'s functions on `jpeg_compress_struct` or `jpeg_decompress_struct` without first calling the `jpeg_create_compress` or `jpeg_create_decompress` functions respectively.